# How replace webView by custom webView?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I has my activity that contain only one webView.

Activity write on Kotlin:

```
    class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
           // some code here
            verticalLayout {
                webView {//replace this by custom webView (ObservableWebView)
                    setOnLongClickListener(object : View.OnLongClickListener {
                        override fun onLongClick(v: View): Boolean {
                            return true
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
       }
    }
```

Also I has custom webView - ObservableWebView.java:

```
public class ObservableWebView extends WebView {
 // some code here
}
```

I want to replace webView with my custom webView (**ObservableWebView**) in class **MyActivity.kt**. How I can do this?

Comment: just do one thing , copy all your MyActivity.java class code and paste in MyActivity.kt class...android studio do every thing for you.

Comment: I want to replace webView by custom webView (ObservableWebView). How I can do this?

Comment: I found solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45255458/android-kotlin-custom-webview-cannot-be-invoked-as-a-function-the-function/45258248#45258248

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add your custom webview following anko syntax, you need to extend the DSL as stated on the [docs](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Layouts#is-it-extensible)

Follow the `MapView` example but use your `ObservableWebView` instead.

- https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Layouts#is-it-extensible