# Android: Kotlin: custom webView - cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found

Tags: android, kotlin

I has one activity (**ContactActivity.kt**) that contain only one webView component. Activity write on Kotlin.

I want to replace webView with my custom webView (**ObservableWebView.java**).

So here code (**MyActivity.kt**):

```
class ContactActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            verticalLayout {
     val observableWebView = object : ObservableWebView(MainApp.getAppContext())
            observableWebView { // error here
                    setOnLongClickListener(object : View.OnLongClickListener {
                        override fun onLongClick(v: View): Boolean {
                            return true
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
       }
    }
```

Also I has custom webView - ObservableWebView.java:

```
public class ObservableWebView extends WebView {
    private OnScrollChangedCallback mOnScrollChangedCallback;

    public ObservableWebView(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ObservableWebView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ObservableWebView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(final int l, final int t, final int oldl, final int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if (mOnScrollChangedCallback != null) mOnScrollChangedCallback.onScroll(l, t);
    }

    public OnScrollChangedCallback getOnScrollChangedCallback() {
        return mOnScrollChangedCallback;
    }

    public void setOnScrollChangedCallback(final OnScrollChangedCallback onScrollChangedCallback) {
        mOnScrollChangedCallback = onScrollChangedCallback;
    }

    /**
     * Impliment in the activity/fragment/view that you want to listen to the webview
     */
    public static interface OnScrollChangedCallback {
        public void onScroll(int l, int t);
    }
}
```

But I get compile error in **MyActivity.kt**:

```
Error:(145, 13) Expression 'observableWebView' of type '<no name provided>' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend Anko to support your custom View with an extension function like this one (see the docs [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Layouts#is-it-extensible)):

```
inline fun ViewManager.observableWebView(theme: Int = 0, init: ObservableWebView.() -> Unit): ObservableWebView {
    return ankoView({ ObservableWebView(it) }, theme, init)
}
```

Then creating one and setting a listener would look like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    verticalLayout {
        observableWebView {
            setOnLongClickListener {
                Log.d("WEBVIEW", "on long click")
                true
            }
            onLongClick {
                Log.d("WEBVIEW", "on long click")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code shows off too different ways to create the long click listener, of course you do not need both.

The first one is the classic way, it uses `WebView`'s `setOnLongClickListener` function, and [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions) to create a listener instance with a lambda. You have to return a boolean value here to indicate whether you've handled the event, or you want it to propagate.

The second way, using `onLongClick` is a way to do it with Anko. Above `0.10.0`, this will use coroutines. Here, you don't get the option to return a boolean value.

---

Optionally, if you want to be able to use the `observableWebView()` syntax as well, you can create another extension that delegates to this previous extension:

```
inline fun ViewManager.observableWebView() = observableWebView {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just call

```
observableWebView.setOnLongClickListener
```

It looks like you're trying to "invoke" a method on `observableWebView`, but it's not a function type?